# How can I resolve an async request before conditionally routing in AngularJS UI Router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is a problem I've seen discussed in a few posts around Stack, but I haven't found a clear answer that actually works for me. I expect this to be a common problem, so alternate approaches would be fine too.

Basic concept is that I wish to conditionally display one of two states when a user visits the site. I have an API call to my external server to check if the user's session is active. If so, I can route to the 'home' page, otherwise I route to the 'welcome' page.

The problem is that I don't know how to achieve this.

My initial idea was to create a `resolve` object in the home state, and resolve the `api.isLoggedIn` call there first. That would stall the transition so that I could check the state `$stateChangeStart` event, and then call `event.preventDefault` if necessary.

The problem with this is that onStateChangeStart is called *before* the resolve method, so I cannot know whether the user is logged in before the state change.

At the moment I'm thinking that the only way I can achieve this is by presenting an initial state whose controller will check if the user is logged in and then manually call a state change based on the response.

Is there a more idiomatic solution?

Comment: Use $stateChangeSuccess instead, it will fire after resolve. You can use $location in there to change routes.

Comment: Have you tried using [$urlRouter](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouter)? It might be really helpful for your situation.

Comment: This does sound perfect! I've rolled a kinda shitty solution for the meantime, but I'll try this out on the next project for sure.

If you'd like to turn this comment into an answer I'll accept it.